# What are some problems people can solve but computers cannot

Tags: algorithms

I want to create a program that makes problems that people can solve but computers would struggle with. I've read that human language is very difficult and CAPTCHA looks pretty promising. Basically I want to make puzzles, riddles, and codes that a person could figure out with some effort but that cannot be automated. Any ideas or easy to understand reading materials on the subject would be appreciated, most of what I have been able to find goes right over my head haha.

Comment: Apparently [folding towels](https://www.npr.org/sections/money/2015/05/19/407736307/robots-are-really-bad-at-folding-towels) is one of those problems.

Comment: [Robotics](https://youtu.be/1iRfSjkLfNQ) might have some things some things for you.

Comment: CAPTCHAs look like they meet all your stated requirements.  Since you asked for readings, have you read about CAPTCHAs?  There's *lots* written on the subject (you can spend some quality time on Google Scholar if you like). Do you find them not fully satisfactory, and if not, why not?  Identifying whether CAPTCHAs meet your needs or not, and if not why not, might help you craft a more specific question.

Comment: Well I've been reading that AI are getting better and better at recognizing the letters. I'm wondering what are some things that will always be impossible or challenging for a computer to do.